# Dynamic Proxy URL for store.load() in MVC architecture with Ext JS

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4

I want to change the proxy of a store before (!) it is loaded. The specific problem in this case is that I do not find the right moment, when to load.

In detail:

I have created a MVC-model by creating a view, a controller, a model, and a store as defined by EXTJS4 architecture. The view is a grid panel. It defines the store within its own define statement:

```
Ext.define('P.view.MyView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.MyView',
    ...
    store: 'MyStore',
    ...
}
```

When I load the store with "autoload:true" everything works fine, but of course the proxy is then static as defined in the code. When I do not use "autoload" and try to set "extraParams" and the load the store in the "initComponent" of my view like:

```
initComponent: function() {
    ...
    this.store.load();    
    ....
```

I get an error: Object "MyStore" has no method 'load'.

How should I do it?

Comment: you are sure is not a syntax error ... this.store.load();

Comment: Yes, it has been. Is corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `this.store.load()` in initComponent the store is not initialized yet. The property `this.store` is string at the moment of calling. You have to call for loading after your widget's parent `initComponent` (where the store initialization is happening) was called:

```
initComponent: function() {
    ...
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.store.load();    
    ....
```

Comment: Additional question: Where and how should I influence the "extraParams". I cannot do this within the view itself (i.e. before store.load ), because only the component implementing the view (and its store) knows the details.

Comment: @heinob, it depends on circumstances. Under what conditions extraParams should be changed?

Comment: I have a tabpanel. The gridpanel (MyView) is added as a new tab. The contents of the grid (store loaded through proxy) depends on circumstances outside the view, but is known by the function which adds the tab/view.

Comment: @heinob, I think the best place would be the function which adds the tab/view. If this function is in controller you can access your store by controller's store getter. F.i. if your store is called 'MyStore' you can access it via `this.getMyStoreStore()`.

Answer (score 5):

I would add that another common way to load data at the last moment is with the afterrender listener on the grid itself like this:

```
       listeners: {
             afterrender: function(grid) {
                grid.store.getProxy().url = 'request/my.json'; //modify your URL
                grid.store.load();    
             }
        }
```

As you can see you can also influence your store and proxy settings. This help with reuse of the stores for similar grids.